# mypy: define types for specific keys in dynamic dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

I have the following dictionary representing a person that could be one of many variations. Here are just a few:

```
person = {"name": "Johnny"}
person = {"name": "Johnny", "age": 25}
person = {"name": "Johnny", "age": 25, "active": True}
```

I'm extracting certain keys and using them to print a statement. The problem arises in the type hints, where I'm getting an error saying `Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "object", variable has type "Optional[str]")` when I run mypy on the script:

```
name: Optional[str] = person.get("name")  # mypy error here
age: Optional[int] = person.get("age")    # mypy error here
if name and age:
    print(f"In 5 years, {name} will be {age + 5} years old")
```

To solve this the `mypy_extensions.TypedDict` type seemed promising, but it appears I can't have missing or extra keys:

```
from mypy_extensions import TypedDict
PersonDict = TypedDict("PersonDict", {"name": str, "age": int})

# ERROR: Key 'age' missing for TypedDict "PersonDict"
person: PersonDict = {"name": "Johnny"}

# ERROR: Extra key 'active' for TypedDict "PersonDict"
person: PersonDict = {"name": "Johnny", "age": 25, "active": True}
```

Is there anyway to define types for specific keys in a dictionary, even if the keys in that dictionary are dynamic?

Comment: I'm a little confused. Mypy is telling you that since the dictionary is dynamic, any `get` on it may return `None`, and that you should type the variables as `Optional[str]` (i.e., `Union[None, str]`). Isn't that exactly right according to your code?

Comment: @JoshKarpel mypy doesn't attach a type to the `name` key in the dict; so it assumes it's simply an `object` and throws an error when I try to give it a type of `Optional[str]`

Comment: Then you should declare the dictionary to be a `Dict[str, str]`, no?

Comment: @JoshKarpel That's not accurate either, since `age` is mapped to an `int`, not a `str`.

Comment: Ah, good point. It really sounds like you're fighting against the type checker here - maybe `Person` should be a class with individually-typed fields, probably a dataclass. The layer where you take JSON data and turn it into a dataclass will be dynamically typed, but after you turn it into a `Person`, it can be statically typed.

Comment: You can pass `total=False` to the `TypedDict` constructor to allow missing keys, but allowing extra keys does not seem possible.

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer that worked thanks! If you post a solution as choose it as the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding `total=False` to your TypedDict will allow missing keys:

```
PersonDict = TypedDict("PersonDict", {"name": str, "age": int}, total=False)
```

https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/more_types.html#totality

Allowing additional keys not in the schema does not seem possible.